# Angular 11 - ng serve - Option "sourceMap" is deprecated

Tags: angular, angular-compiler-cli, angular-builder

I updated Angular project from Angular 10 to 11x. Everything works normally, except for one warning on running project using `ng serve` (without any option in ng serve). The warning is:

> Option "sourceMap" is deprecated: Use the "sourceMap" option in the browser builder instead.

The warning is not presented in `ng build`.

Here is how browser builder part in `angular.json` of the project looks like:

```
"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/my-app",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "sourceMap": true,
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
```

Something related has changed in Angular 11? How to remove this warning?

Comment: What is your "serve" section in `angular.json`?

Comment: I actually tried the configuration you posted and I dont get the same warning. I don't think its relevant

Comment: @HTN, here is "serve" section in my `angular.json`:
"serve": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
  "options": {
 "browserTarget": "my-app:build",
 "sourceMap": {
   "scripts": true,
   "styles": true,
   "vendor": true
 }
  },
  "configurations": {
 "production": {
   "browserTarget": "easyproduction-web:build:production"
 }
  }
},

Comment: I don't understand the question. The warning says: "Option "sourceMap" is deprecated". In your serve configuration you have `"sourceMap": { "scripts": true, "styles": true, "vendor": true } }`. What exactly is unclear with this warning?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to remove `sourceMap` from `serve --> options --> sourceMap`, which is deprecated.

Comment: Rightly pointed out, use of `sourceMap` is deprecated now: https://angular.io/cli/serve#options

Comment: I didn't have this flag in serve configuration, but suddenly ( after update) debugging stopped working. I found that sourceMaps are not generated anymore. Putting this deprecated flag in solved the issue. What has changed in default sourceMap configuration ?

Answer (score 13):

I was confused by some of the answers, these options aren't really deprecated but should now be specified in the proper `"build"` section of `angular.json`, not `"serve"`.

Comment: In "serve" section, it is deprecated: https://angular.io/cli/serve#options

Comment: Yes we agree. Just pointing out that it doesn't mean you can't turn source maps on or off for ng serve, as long as you put it in the right build section. Just wanted to make it clear in case there are other people like me who didn't get it.

Comment: Just upgrade to Angular13 from Angular 12 and use to have `ng serve --source-map=true --prod=false --watch=true` but now it says `--source-map` is  an "unknown option". I have to use `ng serve` as I have to run HTTPS/SSL locally for our system. But now I have no source maps? Any ideas?

Answer (score 12):

Based on previous comments, here is a **working configuration** :

In `angular.json`, add this configuration to
`projects.[NAME_OF_YOUR_PROJECT].architect.serve.configurations` :

```
"dev": {
  "browserTarget": "[NAME_OF_YOUR_PROJECT]:build:dev"
}
```

Like that :

```
...
"architect": {
  "serve": {
    ...
    "configurations": {
      "production": {
        ...
      },
      "dev": {
        "browserTarget": "[NAME_OF_YOUR_PROJECT]:build:dev"
      }
    }
  },
  ...
```

Then, add the corresponding `"dev"` configuration in `projects.[NAME_OF_YOUR_PROJECT].architect.build.configurations` :

```
"dev": {
  "optimization": false,
  "sourceMap": true
}
```

like this example :

```
...
"architect": {
  "build": {
    ...
    "configurations": {
      "production": {
        ...
      },
      "dev": {
        "optimization": false,
        "sourceMap": true
      }
    }
  },
...
```

Now you just have to edit the `"start"` script command in `package.json` :

```
...
"scripts": {
  "start": "ng serve --configuration=dev",
  ...
```

and you should retrieve sources map files in your favorite browser !

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This helped me fix the problem too, migrating from Angular 10 to Angular 13.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67647471/angular-12-source-map-is-missing-in-browser   this answer helped me. There were more properties that I added in the architect.build.configurations.dev section that fixed my issue

Answer (score 2):

Using Angular15 you have to set the `sourceMap` and similar settings in the **angular.json** file under

`architect -> build -> configurations -> development`

then you can load this configuration via `serve` using the development `browserTarget` setting it under

`architect -> serve -> configurations -> development`

**angular.json** example:

```json
    {
      ...
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            ...
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              ...
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          ...
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "ng-app-15:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "ng-app-15:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        ...
      }
    }
```

Then, you can run the following command to use ng serve with `sourceMap` properly and with the possibility of using the `debugger`.

`ng serve --configuration=development`**strong text**

Note: if this answer will expire for some reason, you can always install the latest version of Angular and run "ng new app", by default it will show you the correct angular.json configurations to use properly `sourceMap` and similar settings.